# Display file in java swing GUI

Tags: java, swing, filereader

Having problems displaying a ".txt" file in a java swing Gui.

I have the code to read the .txt file and display it in the cmd window but cant seem to link it so it will display in the Gui.

here is the code that reads the file:

```
import java.io.*;
public class ReadFile {
public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException{

String inputLine = "";
FileReader inputFile = new FileReader( "player.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputFile);

System.out.println( "\nThe contents of the file player.txt are ");

// Read lines of text from the file, looping until the
// null character (ctrl-z) is endountered
while( ( inputLine = br.readLine()) != null){
  System.out.println(inputLine); // Write to the screen
}
br.close();         // Close the stream

}  // end of main method
}  //  end of class
```

here is the code for the Swing Gui

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame{

private JButton button;

//Set Hight and Width of Interface
private static final int WIDTH = 500;
private static final int HEIGHT = 500;

//Method to Create Inteface
public GUI(){
    createComponents();
    createDisplay();
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

//An Action Listener To Contorl Action Preformed
class ClickListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

    }
}
//Method to Create Button
private void createComponents(){
    button = new JButton("Click Me");
    ActionListener listener = new ClickListener();
    button.addActionListener(listener);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(button);
    add(panel);

}
//Method To Create Display
private void createDisplay(){
    JTextArea myArea = new JTextArea();

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.add(myArea);
    add(panel1);
}
}
```

and here is the code to run the Swing GUI

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUITest{
public static void main (String [] agrs){

    JFrame frame = new GUI();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);


}
}
```

All files are in the same folder on my laptop along with the .txt file. And i am using TextPad to code and compile.

all help would be grate

thanks
Derek

Comment: All of the code to read the file runs in `main()`...that's not what you want from that.  You'd rather create methods that do exactly that but not in `main()`.

Comment: yup that is exactly what i want to be able to do Makoto. but when i try to do it i get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> here is the code that reads the file:

Get rid of that code, it is not needed.

JTextArea has a `read(...)` method that you can use to read the text file directly into the text area.

Comment: Tried `myArea.read(Reader, "player.txt");` where i am setting up the text area but keep getting an error?? is it that i am using the `read( )` wrong??

Comment: Yes, you are using the method wrong. You still need to create the BufferedReader the way you did before. Then you just use `textArea.read(br, null);`.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an object of the `ReadFile` class in the `Actionlistener` class and call `ReadFile`'s main method.

Comment: thanks for the help Vineet, how would i get it to display in the Gui after creating the object??

Comment: Thereafter you can use `JLabel` to display all that data in GUI.

Comment: You can't use a JLabel to display multiple lines of text (unless the text in an HTML file).